# How to constrain the signature of callable objects in C++?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename TCallable>
void Fun(TCallable c){
...
}
```

How can I indicate that the `c` in the foregoing code must have some specific signature (let's say `int(double, double)`) without using std::function?

Comment: By using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of templates?

Comment: If you want it to be a specific signature, why is it a template?

Comment: If you don't care about performance hit, then std::function will help you, otherwise you may have to resort to std::enable_if and type traits trickery.

Comment: @tenfour Because it has to accept callable objects and I don't want to use std::function.

Comment: How specific do you want the constraint to be, and why?

Comment: @MSalters Actually it's fine without the constraint(That's why I don't want `std::function`). I just believe it would better to have one.

Comment: Callable objects don't necessarily have a single signature.

Comment: @Mike What do you mean by "there is constraint by using std::function"? What constraint is added? Could you please clarify, thanks!

Comment: @MarsonMao `std::function<int(double, double)>` constrains the signature to be `in(double, double)` of course.

Comment: @Mike I think I get it. So you want something "compatible" with `int(double, double)`, but not "exactly" `int(double, double)`, right? If you use `std::function<int(double, double)>` the it must be something exactly being `int(double, double)`, right?

Comment: @Mike Sorry for asking so much, but I really want to understand this question thoughrouly, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you can just add `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(c(0.0,0.0)), int>::value, "c must take two doubles and return int")`.

Comment: what is `is_same_type<>`?

Comment: @Walter: My bad, the C++11 `<type_traits>` template is actually just `std::is_same>`. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want several `Fun` functions for different `Callable`s, then `static_assert()` won't help you, but you can use SFINAE, e.g.

```
// version for int(double,double)
template<typename Callable>
auto Fun(Callable c)
-> typename
   std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(c(0.0,0.0)),int>::value>::type
{ /* ... */ }

// version for int(double,double,double)
template<typename Callable>
auto Fun(Callable c)
-> typename
   std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(c(0.0,0.0,0.0)),int>::value>::type
{ /* ... */ }
```